# How to play all songs in windows player in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

Could you please help to write a script to play all songs in particular folder via vbscript.

```
Set wmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
wmp.openPlayer("xxx.mp3")
```

The above script can run a single file.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

This Vbscript **PlayListSongs.vbs** scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs and create a playlist in a text file in order to play it in the background.
So just give a try ;)

```
'***********************************Description*************************************
'This Vbscript scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs like .mp3 .wav .....
'And create a playlist in a text file in order to play it in the background.
'© Hackoo © 2015
'***********************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    Dim Folder,File,fso,MyPlayList,Temp,oExec,ws,Title,WaitingMsg
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    Folder = Browse4Folder()
    MyPlayList = Folder & "\MyPlayList.txt"
    If fso.FileExists(MyPlayList) Then
        fso.DeleteFile(MyPlayList)
    End If
    Title = "Looking for songs in "& DblQuote(Folder) & " using Vbscript © Hackoo 2015"
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait... Searching for songs into : <font color=Yellow>"& DblQuote(Folder) & "</font> is in progress..."
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    Call Pause(10)
    Call Scan4Songs(Folder)
    Call FermerProgressBar()
    Call Play(MyPlayList)
End If
'*********************************************************
Sub Play(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Sound,Xwmp
    Dim fso,F,ReadME,PlayList,i,Ws,Copyright,Name,Duration
    Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2015"
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Ws.popup Err.Description & VbCrlF &_
        "No media file found !","3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
        wscript.quit()
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    PlayList = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.currentPlaylist.Clear
    For i = Lbound(PlayList) to Ubound(PlayList)
        Set Xwmp = Sound.newMedia(PlayList(i))
        Sound.currentPlaylist.insertItem(i),Xwmp
        Sound.Controls.Play()   
        Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
            wscript.sleep 100
        Loop
        wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
    Next    
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
    Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
    Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders for songs"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Scan4Songs(Folder)
    Dim File,Ext,i,SubFolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For each File in Folder.Files
        Ext = Array("mp3","wav","ogg","asf","aa3","m3v","midi")
        For i = LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(Ext(i)) Then 
                Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,File.Path)
            end if
        Next
    Next
    For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call Scan4Songs(SubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,strContents)
    Dim fso,ts
    Const ForAppending= 8
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(MyPlayList,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strContents
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 490,110"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'**********************************************************************************************
```

**EDIT : 19/08/2015 Another version**

In this example, you can scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs like .mp3. And create a playlist **(MyPlayList.m3u)** file in order to play it with Windows Media Player.

**[VBS] PlayListSongsWMP.vbs**

```
'***********************************Description*************************************
'This Vbscript scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs like .mp3
'And create a playlist file in order to play it with Windows Media Player.
'Created on 05/04/2015 © Hackoo © 2015
'***********************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    Dim Folder,File,fso,MyPlayList,Temp,oExec,ws,Title,WaitingMsg
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    Folder = Browse4Folder()
    MyPlayList = Folder & "\MyPlayList.m3u"
    If fso.FileExists(MyPlayList) Then
        fso.DeleteFile(MyPlayList)
    End If
    Title = "Looking for songs in "& DblQuote(Folder) & " using Vbscript © Hackoo 2015"
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait... Searching for songs into : <font color=Yellow>"& DblQuote(Folder) & "</font> is in progress..."
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    Call Pause(10)
    Call Scan4Songs(Folder)
    Call FermerProgressBar()
    Call Play(MyPlayList)
End If
'*********************************************************
Sub Play(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Sound,Ws,Copyright
    Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2015"
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Ws.popup Err.Description & VbCrlF &_
        "No media file found !","3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
        wscript.quit()
    Else
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.OpenPlayer(File)
    End If
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
    Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
    Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders for songs"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Scan4Songs(Folder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim File,Ext,item,SubFolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For each File in Folder.Files
        Ext = Array("mp3")
        For each item in Ext
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(item) Then 
                Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,File.Path)
            end if
        Next
    Next
    For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call Scan4Songs(SubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,strContents)
    Dim fso,ts
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(MyPlayList,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine "#UTF8: "& strContents
    ts.WriteLine strContents
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 490,110"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a vbscript that can read from a text file a list of path of songs **(Local or Online)**, may be can give you an idea and you can improve it of course :)

So to test this script, you must create a text file named **PlayList.txt**

```
http://soundjay.com/mechanical/bomb-falling-and-exploding-01.mp3
http://soundbible.com/mp3/Evil_laugh_Male_9-Himan-1598312646.mp3
http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Intro_DJ.mp3
http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Best of Avicii Megamix 2014.mp3
http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/David_Guetta_Miami_2014.mp3
http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Megamix 90.mp3
```

And test it with this code :

```
'**********************Description************************
'Play a PlayList contained in a text file © Hackoo © 2014
'*********************************************************
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Call Play()
If Err <> 0 Then
    Ws.popup Err.Description,"3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
    Err.Clear
End If
'*********************************************************
Sub Play()
    Dim Sound,Xwmp
    Dim File,fso,F,ReadME,PlayList,i,Ws,Copyright,Name,Duration
    Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2014"
    File = "PlayList.txt"
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FileExists(File) Then
        Ws.popup Err.Description,"3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
    End IF
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    PlayList = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.currentPlaylist.Clear
    For i = Lbound(PlayList) to Ubound(PlayList)
        Set Xwmp = Sound.newMedia(PlayList(i))
        Sound.currentPlaylist.insertItem(i),Xwmp
        Sound.Controls.Play()   
        Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
            wscript.sleep 100
        Loop
        wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
    Next    
End Sub
'***********************************************************
```