# Move files to folders based on first X characters of filename (vbs)

Tags: windows, logging, vbscript

Hello my coding friends.

Sorry to ask this, but I thought it might be quicker to ask if someone has a script like this lying around.

I have about 2000+ files of audio mp3 files logged for a radio station I'm at, and I'd like to put them in to folders according to their recorded log date.
(Yes, I've now fixed the recording to do this correctly from now on, but this is in referent to what I've been doing with it: https://stephenmonro.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/setting-up-an-audio-logger/ )

The files I have are like this: (`YYYYMMDD_HH00`)

```
logs\20150424_0300.mp3
logs\20150424_0400.mp3
logs\20150424_0500.mp3
etc.
```

What I'd like is something like this:

```
\logs\8 digit date\filename with the same 8 digit date.mp3
```

Actual

```
\logs\20150424\20150424_0300.mp3
\logs\20150424\20150424_0400.mp3
\logs\20150424\20150424_0500.mp3
etc.
```

This is my pseudo code, I've made, but as I'm a little pressed for time and don't have hours to mess around guessing, I just wondered if anyone knew how to do it quickly.

A .VBS file is my prefered language.

```
Do
  Read a filenames first 8 characters {left(8, filename)}  (the date)
  If not exist, create a folder called that first 8 characters
  Move that file into the folder name
Loop (until all files are moved to the right locations)
```

Comment: After having solved your problem,you can try if you like this script : How to play all songs in windows player in vbscript ?

Here are two versions one to play the playlist in the background and the other one with wmpalyer.exe minimized !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327153/how-to-play-all-songs-in-windows-player-in-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Hi @Hackoo, while the files are mp3, I just needed them to be organised. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudocode looks spot on to me. Assuming every file in your `logs` folder is consistently named, here's how it could be accomplished using the `FileSystemObject` library:

```
Const LOGS_FOLDER = "c:\logs"

Dim objFSO, objFile, strDate, strSub
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(LOGS_FOLDER).Files

    strDate = Left(objFile.Name, 8)
    strSub  = objFSO.BuildPath(LOGS_FOLDER, strDate)

    ' Create the folder if it doesn't already exist...
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strSub) Then objFSO.CreateFolder strSub

    ' Move the file into its proper folder. Use "\" to indicate dest is folder...
    objFile.Move strSub & "\"

Next
```

Comment: Genius. It's not everyday I have a 007 helping me. Thanks mate, works wonderfully. :)