# Batch file to make a random selection from a directory?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am working with an Artificial Intelligence on my computer and I have a simple command where I say "Play me a happy song". What I would like that to do is trigger a batch file that will go to a file in which I have a variety of happy songs.

I don't have a large amount knowledge with batch, especially when it comes to randoms. I just want it so it will randomly select the song from the file. Would this be better as a .vbs? I know nothing about those except how to make the file. If it's the batch and you're able to help me it would be greatly appreciated if you could explain a little bit of it to me so I can hopefully do more of these on my own.

The file that holds the mp3s is C:\Users\ptldk\Documents\Batch\Batch Support\Random Happy Music Playlist

Thank you

Comment: Check out `%RANDOM%` -- type `set /?` and go down clise to the end of the help text; such number could be taken as a basis for your selection...

Comment: First, take a look at those vbscripts : one to play the playlist in the background and the other one with wmpalyer.exe minimized ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327153/how-to-play-all-songs-in-windows-player-in-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go through folders and files, consider to use `for` loop and `forfiles` command. What you need to do is:
1) Loops through the `Music_PATH` and search for only files with `.mp3` extension.
2) Create an array (even though batch don't have this feature, but we can do it manually), and assign it with the file name. `%%~nxa` removes quotation marks and add extension at the end of the file name.
3) Since `%random%` returns value between 0-32767, and we don't need such big values, 
`%random% %% VALUE(e.g: 10)` will return value between 0-9. This is good, because we are playing around with arrays, *value 0 will be the 1st element of the array (which is the 1st mp3 file)*, and 0 is a part of the random range!
4)`Start` the mp3 file with your default program (VLC, WMPlayer, etc...), Windows will ask for the default program if it's necessary.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Music_PATH=C:\Users\ptldk\Documents\Batch\Batch Support\Random Happy Music Playlist"
set counter=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('forfiles /p "%Music_PATH%" /m *mp3') do (
    set Rand_PATH[!counter!]=%%~nxa
    set /a counter+=1
)

set /a Random_Music=%random% %% %counter%
set "Full_PATH=%Music_PATH%\!Rand_PATH[%Random_Music%]!"

echo Random Music & echo. & echo !Rand_PATH[%Random_Music%]!
start "" "%Full_PATH%"

pause >nul
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this vbscript

```
'***********************************Description*************************************
'This Vbscript scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs like .mp3 .mp4 .wav .....
'And create a playlist in a text file in order to play it in the background.
'© Hackoo © 2015
'***********************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
    Dim Folder,File,fso,MyPlayList,Temp,oExec,ws,Title,WaitingMsg
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    Folder = Browse4Folder()
    MyPlayList = Folder & "\MyPlayList.txt"
    If fso.FileExists(MyPlayList) Then
        fso.DeleteFile(MyPlayList)
    End If
    Title = "Looking for songs in "& DblQuote(Folder) & " using Vbscript © Hackoo 2015"
    WaitingMsg = "Please wait... Searching for songs into : <font color=Yellow>"& DblQuote(Folder) & "</font> is in progress..."
    Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
    Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
    Call Pause(10)
    Call Scan4Songs(Folder)
    Call FermerProgressBar()
    Call Play(MyPlayList)
End If
'*********************************************************
Sub Play(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Sound,Xwmp
    Dim fso,F,ReadME,PlayList,i,Ws,Copyright,Name,Duration
    Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2015"
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Ws.popup Err.Description & VbCrlF &_
        "No media file found !","3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
        wscript.quit()
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    PlayList = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    Sound.settings.volume = 100
    Sound.currentPlaylist.Clear
    For i = Lbound(PlayList) to Ubound(PlayList)
        Set Xwmp = Sound.newMedia(PlayList(i))
        Sound.currentPlaylist.insertItem(i),Xwmp
        Sound.Controls.Play()   
        Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
            wscript.sleep 100
        Loop
        wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
    Next    
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
    Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
    Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders for songs"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Scan4Songs(Folder)
    Dim File,Ext,i,SubFolder
    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
    For each File in Folder.Files
        Ext = Array("mp4","mp3","wav","ogg","asf","aa3","m3v","midi")
        For i = LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(Ext(i)) Then 
                Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,File.Path)
            end if
        Next
    Next
    For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Call Scan4Songs(SubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,strContents)
    Dim fso,ts
    Const ForAppending= 8
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(MyPlayList,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strContents
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
    fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 500,100"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a Randomize function to the great code from Hackoo.

```
'***********************************Description*************************************
'This Vbscript scan into a folder and its subfolders for songs like .mp3 .mp4 .wav .....
'And create a playlist in a text file in order to play it in the background.
'© Hackoo © 2015
' updated fx 2016
'***********************************************************************************
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
Dim Folder,File,fso,MyPlayList,Temp,oExec,ws,Title,WaitingMsg
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Folder = Browse4Folder()
MyPlayList = Folder & "\_MyPlayList.txt"
If fso.FileExists(MyPlayList) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(MyPlayList)
End If
Title = "Looking for songs in "& DblQuote(Folder) & " using Vbscript © Hackoo 2015"
WaitingMsg = "Please wait... Searching for songs into : <font color=Yellow>"& DblQuote(Folder) & "</font> is in progress..."
Call CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)'Creation of Waiting Bar
Call LancerProgressBar() 'Launch of the Waiting Bar
Call Pause(10)
Call Scan4Songs(Folder)
Call FermerProgressBar()
Call Play(MyPlayList)
End If
'*********************************************************
Sub Play(File)
On Error Resume Next
Dim Sound,Xwmp
Dim fso,F,ReadME,PlayList,i,Ws,Copyright,Name,Duration
Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2015"
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
If Err <> 0 Then
    Ws.popup Err.Description & VbCrlF &_
    "No media file found !","3",Err.Description & Copyright,VbCritical
    wscript.quit()
End If
ReadMe = F.ReadAll
PlayList = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.settings.volume = 100
Sound.currentPlaylist.Clear
For i = Lbound(PlayList) to Ubound(PlayList)
    Set Xwmp = Sound.newMedia(PlayList(i))
    Sound.currentPlaylist.insertItem(i),Xwmp
    Sound.Controls.Play()   
    Do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop
    wscript.sleep(int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
Next    
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
    With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
        " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
        AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
    End With   
End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Browse4Folder()
Dim objShell,objFolder,Message
Message = "Please select a folder in order to scan into it and its subfolders for songs"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,Message,1,"c:\Programs")
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Browse4Folder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'*********************************************************************************************
Function Scan4Songs(Folder)
Dim File,Ext,i,SubFolder
Dim listArr(),RandArr()
Dim j,n,boo

j=0
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Folder)
For each File in Folder.Files
    Ext = Array("mp4","mp3","wav","ogg","asf","aa3","m3v","midi")
    For i = LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(File.name)) = LCase(Ext(i)) Then 
            ''Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,File.Path)
            ''Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,File.Name) 
            if j=0 then 
               redim listArr(1)
            else
               redim PRESERVE listArr(j+1)
            end if  
            ListArr(j)=File.Path
            j=j+1 
        end if
    Next
Next
if j > 0 then 
   Redim RandArr(ubound(listArr)) 
   for i=lbound(listArr) to ubound(listArr)
       Randomize
       n = int(Rnd * ubound(listArr))
       boo =false
       while not boo
          if IsEmpty(RandArr(n)) then 
             RandArr(n)=ListArr(i)
             boo=true  
          else
             n=n+1
             if n=ubound(listArr)+1 then 
                n=0
             end if 
          end if
       wend
   next
   for i=lbound(RandArr) to ubound(RandArr)
       if not IsEmpty(RandArr(i)) then 
          Call MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,RandArr(i)) 
       end if
   next
end if 

For each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
    Call Scan4Songs(SubFolder.Path)
Next
End Function
    '*********************************************************************************************
Sub MakePlayListFile(MyPlayList,strContents)
Dim fso,ts
Const ForAppending= 8
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(MyPlayList,ForAppending,True)
ts.WriteLine strContents
ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Title,WaitingMsg)
Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Title & "</Title>"
fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER>"
fhta.WriteLine "<marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & WaitingMsg &"</font></marquee>"
fhta.WriteLine "<img src=""data:image/gif;base64,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"" />"
fhta.WriteLine "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 500,100"
fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""DarkOrange"" "
fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Secs)    
Wscript.Sleep(Secs * 1000)    
End Sub   
'******************************************************************************************
```