# Playing folder full of files from Disc in Windows Media Player in Batch

Tags: file, batch-file, video, windows-media-player

I'm making a batch file to play AVI files in a folder in Windows Media Player (WMP11). They must be able to play in this player so I can not use VLC.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem as simple as:

```
start wmplayer folder\*.avi
```

The media player website shows that it can play a single file, how can I get it to play all of a type, or make a temporary playlist so they can be played?

Comment: You can try this vbscript ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327153/how-to-play-all-songs-in-windows-player-in-vbscript?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Borrowed from this : **[SuperUser.com
>   Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1000599)**.
>  I'll put it here for
>   convenience & "archive" purposes, also adjusted for your Question.

Make sure **.avi** format is set to always "Open With" Windows Media Player.

1) Open a basic text editor (ie: Notepad) and paste the code shown further below.

2). Save it as **PlayVids.cmd** (or whatever you like but it must be saved as **.cmd**)

3) Double click the **.cmd** file to auto-open all files in folder at once. This gives you an auto-playlist.

**Code for pasting into cmd file :**
 (replace `C:\MyVideos` with your own Disc's drive + folder. If path is wrong it will fail/close)

```
@ECHO OFF
SET VIDFolder=C:\MyVideos
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpVIDTemp.vbs

:VBSDynamicBuild
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.Run "%VIDFolder%"                           >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^a"                               >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
GOTO EOF
```